# ubuntu dock duplicated icon on flatpack app

Tags: gnome, icons, dock

im having duplicated icon in dock while wmclass is not a problem

im running excel via bottles which is under flatpack and icon is appearing as bottles not excel

FYI: i have manually created this application shortcut manually cause bottles is not creating automatically. i have gave i application folder permissions manually still not working

i have added excel.exe wmclass in application menu and its still not working i have check bottles, its wmclass is not excel.exe i did temporary renamed it and it renamed, so its same icon

application details

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Microsoft Excel 2010
Comment=Perform calculations, analyze information, and visualize data in spreadsheets by using Microsoft Excel.
Icon=D702_xlicons.0
Exec=flatpak run --command=bottles-cli com.usebottles.bottles run -p EXCEL -b office32
Categories=Office;Spreadsheet;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=excel.exe
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

lg result

```
Microsoft Excel (Trial) - Book2
wmclass: excel.exe
app: com.usebottles.bottles.desktop
```

apparently wmclass is not matching the icon.

please let me know how its matching with bottles and what other thing gnome checks for matching icons